# Why adding a access control to my security file will end in redirect to a css file?

Tags: php, symfony

I have an unexpected behavior in my symfony application. I'm missing anything, but I don't find what.

In my security file, I add:

```
- { path: ^/, roles: [ROLE_MONITEUR, ROLE_ELEVE, ROLE_SECRETAIRE] }
```

Which says just that the index on my site is accessible only if one of the 3 roles is connected.

If I go to my index being not connected, I was redireted to my login form. GOOD!

If I log in with any account, I was not redirected to my index file, but in a css file of my site. That's a little strange.

If I comment the path line in the access control, it work fine (no control access, but I redireted to the index file).

I'm sure I missing something, but what?
Thanks Best regards

Comment: Can you please share your whole security.yml ?

Comment: Did you set a default_target_path after form login?

Comment: Here my security file. Th default_target_path is set to the index. https://codeshare.io/scndP

Comment: in your controller what is the route to your index?

Comment: The default controller: https://codeshare.io/UZxnz or the security controller: https://codeshare.io/1shjH

Comment: I mean in your routing is it /index or /homepage?

Comment: index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }

Comment: try this before your target_path: always_use_default_target_path: true

Comment: ok, also this work fine, but why? Why it is redirected to a css file? That no sense... THANKS!

Comment: IMHO, it's just because, ehmm, your app caught request to the css file, which is secured by firewall - and after login you were granted needed access and redirected to that css.